Galois Connection Example
I have a question about this example:

Let P be an ordered set. For $A \subseteq P$, define $$A^\triangleright := P \backslash \downarrow A \quad \text{and} \quad A^\triangleleft := P \backslash \uparrow A.$$ Then $(\triangleright, \triangleleft)$ establishes a Galois connection between $\wp(P)$ and $\wp(P)^\partial$.

(Davey and Priestley (2012), Introduction to Lattices and Order, Example 7.24(4), p. 157)
If $P = 2^{2} = \{0, a, b, 1\}$, $A = \{a\}$, and $B = \{a, b, 1\}$,then we have $A^\triangleright = \{b, 1\} \subseteq B$, but $A \not\supseteq B^\triangleleft = \{0\}$. Am I missing something?

Realized shortly after posting that the order should be reversed: $A^\triangleright \supseteq B \iff A \subseteq B^\triangleleft$. This is because if $B$ consists only of elements which are not less than any element of $A\left (B \subseteq P \backslash \downarrow A\right)$, then by definition $A$ consists only of elements not greater than any element of $B\left (A \subseteq P \backslash \uparrow B\right)$. Leaving this here in case anyone else has the same specific question that I did.
